# Empty graph when using datetime for x-axis in bar graph with width

Tags: python, datetime, plotly

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import plotly.graph_objects as go

y=[1, 2, 3]

x=[ datetime(2020, 11, 12, 18), 
    datetime(2020, 11, 13, 18), 
    datetime(2020, 11, 14, 18)]

width=1

# make fix 1 or 2 to resolve the issue
fix = 0
if fix == 1:
    x = [0, 1, 2]
elif fix == 2:
    width=None

go.Figure(go.Bar(x=x, y=y, width=width)).show()
```

Hi, the above program renders a blank bar graph for me, try running it for yourself.

If I remove the width tag entirely, the code works again. If I also switch from using datetime in the x axis to integers, it also goes back to normal. This can be demonstrated by changing `fix` to 1 or 2 in the above program.

It seems like an interaction between the width field and datetime is causing an issue.

Can someone confirm if this is a bug? User error? Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In plotly, widths are taken as milliseconds when x-axis is of datetime type.

If you want your widths to give widths in form of days, you need to give `num_days*1000*3600*24`. You can add it once in function calling itself and can change widths as if they were in days. e.g. following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go

y=[1, 2, 3]

x=[ datetime(2020, 11, 12, 18), 
    datetime(2020, 11, 13, 18), 
    datetime(2020, 11, 14, 18)]

width= 1
go.Figure(go.Bar(x=x, y=y, width=width*1000*3600*24)).show()
```

produces:

[image]